# Adding all relevant elements in array by a given element

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm for some reason hitting a wall here. I need help figuring this out please. I have the following type of 2D array:

```
[["Bob", "Car", 25000],
["Bob", "TV", 5000],
["Bob", "dog", 1000],
["Sue", "Cat", 1000],
["Sue", "Car", 10000],
["Bob", "shoes", 100],
["Carol", "car", 20000]]
```

And I need to generate an array that is the sum of each of these people's total from the third element of each sub array. ie:

```
[["Bob", 31100],
["Sue", 11000],
["Carol", 20000]]
```

Right now I have a complicated and contrived solution using two loops that iterate through the entire array for each of its own elements. Is there an easier more streamlined way to do this? Especially since my data sets will be quite large. I know ruby has a bunch of awesome enumerables that seem like would fit here, but I can't quite think of how to fit them in.

Comment: 87, when you include an example in your question (a good thing), it's best to assign a variable to each input object. Here that might be `arr = [['Bob', 'Car', 25000],...]`. That way, readers can refer to `arr` in answers and comments without having to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = [["Bob", "Car", 25000],
["Bob", "TV", 5000],
["Bob", "dog", 1000],
["Sue", "Cat", 1000],
["Sue", "Car", 10000],
["Bob", "shoes", 100],
["Carol", "car", 20000]]

hash_result = Hash.new(0)

arr.each do |record|
  hash_result[record[0]] += record[2]
end
```

This will give you a hash result. If you want an array, just call `to_a` on `hash_result`.

Comment: `each` returns `arr`, so you need `hash_result` on a line by itself after the `each` block. I'll delete this comment when you've seen it, so no reply is req'd.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very simple and streamlined solution. Perfect

Answer (score 4):

You can use a counting hash:

```
arr = [["Bob", "Car", 25000],
       ["Bob", "TV", 5000],
       ["Bob", "dog", 1000],
       ["Sue", "Cat", 1000],
       ["Sue", "Car", 10000],
       ["Bob", "shoes", 100],
       ["Carol", "car", 20000]]

arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(name,_,total),h| h[name] += total }
  #=> {"Bob"=>31100, "Sue"=>11000, "Carol"=>20000}
```

[Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) is used to create a hash with a default value of zero. That means that if the hash `h` does not have a key `name`, `h[name]` returns zero. Since:

```
h[name] += total
```

expands to:

```
h[name] = h[name] + total
```

`h[name]` on the right side of the equality returns zero when `h` does not have a key `name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the array of purchases and store the totals in a hash.

```
purchases = [
  ["Bob", "Car", 25000],
  ["Bob", "TV", 5000],
  ["Bob", "dog", 1000],
  ["Sue", "Cat", 1000],
  ["Sue", "Car", 10000],
  ["Bob", "shoes", 100],
  ["Carol", "car", 20000]
]

totals = Hash.new(0)  # initialize the values to 0
purchases.each { |purchase|
  totals[purchase[0]] += purchase[2]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.group_by(&:first).map do |who, group|
  [who, group.map(&:last).inject(:+)]
end
```